# Photoshop's spot-color channel mixing method

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-theory, cmyk, spot-color

Photoshop seems to have a special mode for blending spot-color channels. Let's look at an example: blending full opacity red #ff3c1f with full opacity cyan #1cd4c6.

If I create two spot-color channels with solidity 0% and set their colors to #ff3c1f and #1cd4c6 and fill them with black I get #91550D:

[image: spot color mixing]

Now, I know that combining colors is a complex problem that's not even well-posed. But the result that photoshop gives gets very close to reality most of the time for me. Can anyone help me understand how photoshop does this blending?

I have read on the [Adobe forums](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/928561?start=0&tstart=0) that it's multiplicative blending in CMYK. So I tried to reproduce that with layers, but I am getting #7D4339:

[image: cmyk multiply blending]

I know CMYK is device-dependent but I've tried lots of various profiles but none worked like the spot-color channels. The screenshot is from using the U.S. Web Coated (SWOP) v2 profile.

I tried Multiply blend in Lab and in RGB, but those were even further off.

I would really appreciate any insight on this whatsoever!

Comment: Hi the21st, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: I don't understand what you are seeking here or what the question is. Why are you speaking of Pantone and CMYK but referencing colors with Hex (RGB)??? What's the goal here???

Comment: @Scott I edited the question to not include any references to Pantone colors. The problem remains the same though.

Comment: You still haven't really described any "problem" which you're trying to solve. You've explained differences between spot blending and CMYK blending... but what *exactly* is the problem? Maybe I'm just not seeing it. Yes there's a difference. Why do you need to match blended spots with CMYK? Are you seeking to create a 2C piece which matches a 4C piece? Or are you merely wondering why there's a difference?

Comment: Spot colors are LAB in new photoshops.

Comment: @joojaa, yes they are, but do you know the *math* behind Photoshop's "secret" spot color blend mode? Since it works for any Lab color (not just colors from the color books) it must use some kind of math to create the preview. It seems to be the same algorithm used in *Custom CMYK*'s *Estimate Overprints*, but I can't figure out how it works. I need the algorithm for an app I'm making for myself which can separate an image into two Pantone colors.

Comment: @Wolff probably just a feature of color conversion trough the CMS engine. So just deep end of color management. So the end results depend on what color profile your using etc. Which is why any straight math will fail without exception.

Comment: @joojaa, I really don't think that it's color managed. Try for yourself. The preview of spot colors remain unchanged no matter which profile you use (RGB or CMYK). And works for colors which lies way outside CMYK gamut so it cannot be based on CMYK color profiles. Also the same mixing takes place when you are creating a *Custom CMYK* profile and uses the *Estimate Overprints* feature. I'm pretty sure Photoshop (and other Adobe applications) use some kind of math to make the estimation. Which CMYK profile should it use to estimate the overprint of two arbitrary colors?

Comment: @joojaa. In a CMYK document, the cyan and magenta channel will mix differently than two spot colors with the same lab colors as cyan and magenta. So the spot color blending seems to be unaffected by color profile. Which of course shows the limitations of the method. The CMYK mix is much more accurate. But when it comes to printing Pantone colors for example there are very few ways to color manage (which I can afford). So I'm writing a program in WebGL for 2-color separation where I currently approximate overprint by multiplying the inks. Instead I would like to use Adobe's method.

Comment: @Wolf they just probably have a second profile for spot colors that is always the same. And then they convert that to RGB.

Comment: You might be right @joojaa, but I can't understand how this kind of "secret" color profile could be made. CMYK profiles are made by printing CMYK colors and measuring them. How can this method be done with every possible Lab color? I still believe there is some kind of algorithm behind. Possibly with lots of "magic numbers" which might come from measuring  prints.

Comment: @Wolff no there is just one profile from Spot-lab to RGB. Profiles can be quite complicated.